# How to forward emails in a folder and change the reply to address to the original sender?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a user who wants to redirect any email to other people in their department so that when that person replies to the email it will go back to the person who originally sent it.

I am trying to make VBA code to forward all emails in a specified folder and change the reply to address so that they don't have to manually put it in every time.

```vb
Sub SendFolder()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim ObjMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@us.com").Folders("test")

    For i = MyFolder.Items.Count To 0 Step -1
        Set ObjMail.Subject = MyFolder.Itmes(i).Subject
        Set ObjMail.ReplyRecipients = MyFolder.Itmes(i).ReplyRecipients
        Set ObjMail.Body = MyFolder.Itmes(i).Body
        Set ObjMail.Attachments = MyFolder.Itmes(i).Attachments
        Set ObjMail.BodyFormat = MyFolder.Itmes(i).BodyFormat
        Set ObjMail.To = "test@us.com"
        ObjMail.Send
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

Set ObjMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Then your code would become

```
With ObjMail
    .Subject = MyFolder.Itmes(i).Subject
    .ReplyRecipients = MyFolder.Items(i).ReplyRecipients
    .Body = MyFolder.Items(i).Body
    .Attachments = MyFolder.Items(i).Attachments
    .BodyFormat = MyFolder.Items(i).BodyFormat
    .To = "test@us.com"
    .Send
End with
```

It it runs now, the ReplyTo does not change.

You will want to set the ObjMail's ReplyRecipients property

Something like .ReplyRecipients.Add MyFolder.Items(i).SenderEmailAddress

To simplify the issue, .Forward the mail as is, and set only the ReplyRecipients property.

Check out this alternative. The mail is sent as an attachment. The receiver automatically replies to the original sender.

**Untested**

```
Sub SendFolderItemsAsAttachments()

' Run this VBA code while in Outlook

Dim MyFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim notMyItems as Items
Dim notReplyingToMe as mailitem

Dim i as long

Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("me@us.com").Folders("test")

Set notMyItems = MyFolder.Items

For i = notMyItems.Count To 1 Step -1

   If TypeOf notMyItems(i) Is MailItem Then

       Set notReplyingToMe = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

       With notReplyingToMe

           .Subject = notMyItems(i).Subject & " - " & _
                      notMyItems(i).SenderName
           .HTMLBody = "Redirecting for your action."
           .Attachments.Add notMyItems(i), olEmbeddeditem
           .To = "test@us.com"
           .Send

        End With

        notMyItems(i).Delete

    End If

Next

Set MyFolder = = Nothing
Set notMyItems = Nothing
Set notReplyingToMe = Nothing

End Sub
```